# vim syntax highlighting comments that can be one line or block

Tags: vim, syntax, highlight

this is my first post, so be gentle please!

So, I have input files (.in) for an in-house program. The syntax is as follows (for example):

```
$set (code) $end

$run
(code)
$end

$cmt this is a comment

$cmt this is

a block comment

$end
```

My situation is I want all the `$set` and `$run` to be red with their corresponding `$end` to be red also. Everything in between has to be nominal color (grey).

I simply use the

```
syntax match inCMD "\$SET"
```

for that and it works fine.

Where I have a problem is that I want the `"$CMT"` to be yellow so i use

```
syntax match inCMT "/^\$CMT.*$"
```

The particularity is that `$CMT` does not have to have a corresponding `$END`. So, if there is no `$END` (or that it figures at the end of the same line as `$CMT`, i want the line to be yellow, and the line after to be outside the syntax region. However, if i want to do a block comment and that there is a corresponding `$END` to this `$CMT`, everything inside has to be yellow.

I came up with

[syntax commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm0Pk.png)

but i have a problem on line 14-17 of the 2nd picture:
[syntax example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j88b4.png).

If a `$set` is directly under the `$cmt`, the text inside the $set will be yellow instead of simply white.
The other problem is that the `$end` corresponding to `$set` are white and not red.

How can i solve this?

Thanks a lot!

edit: Syntax file:

```
syntax case ignore 
syntax match inCMT /^\$CMT.*$/
syntax match inCMD "\$SET"
syntax match inCMD "\$RUN"

sy region inCMT matchgroup=inCMT start= /^\$CMT.*$/ end=/\(^\$end\)\|\(^\s*$\)/ contains=inCMD
:sy region inCMD matchgroup=inCMD start= /\v($(SET))/ end=/\(^\$end\)\|\(^\s*$\)/ contained

:hi inCMT ctermfg=yellow 
:hi inCMD ctermfg=red
```

Input file:

```
 $cmt eoipwejf
iowejwed
$end

$set
weoifjwef

$end
$set 
$end

$cmt
$set ewdiw
efef
$end
$set 
effef 
$end

$cmt 
efoiwef
$end

$cmt 
wd
$END

wd

$set
deiuwf = ewoiw
ewofoi we
$end

$cmt fefef
$cmt
efwef
$end

$set 
$set
$set

$cmt ewfoief
wdwwd
$end

$set efopwef


fwfewf
eiojf
$end 

$set 
ere

wd

$cmt
$end

effe

$cmt
wdeoiqwd
$end
edfeef

$run 
goto  
$cmt
wdqwd
$end
```

2nd edit: What i want as final result (colors in brackets)
(y) yellow
(r) red
(n) nominal

```
Block comment:  
$cmt foo (y)
bar (y)
$end (y)

$cmt (y)
   foo (y)
   bar (y)
$end (y)

$cmt (y)
foo (y)

bar(y)
$end (y)

Line comment: 
$cmt (y)
$set (r) foo = bar (n) $end (r)

$cmt foo bar (y)
$set (r) 
foo = bar (n) 
$end (r)
```

I think these are all the cases.

Comment: Maybe this question is for https://superuser.com/

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like *all* comments need to have an `$end`, is that the case? Otherwise, I don't see how you could really differentiate a one-line comment from a block comment. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Please post your syntax commands as text. Post the sample text as text as well (even without the colors), easier to copy & paste to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @filbranden Not all comments need to have a $end. This is why it's hard to get what I want. if it's a 1 line comment, you don't need the $end, but if it's a block comment, you need it.

Comment: @filbrandenIt is as if the $set (or $run) could be the end of the region highlight for the inCMT group if it does not end by a $end first

Comment: So, in `$cmt`,
`$set ewdiw`,
`efef`,
`$end`. Is the `$set ewdiw` a command? Or is it part of a comment? (This looks like a terrible format. I can't imagine how the parser for this will work...)

Comment: in this case, the `$cmt` is a one line comment (without comment) and the`$set` command would actually be read as `$set ewdiw efef $end `. I'm working with a super old program that already has this in place...

Comment: So the comment ends on the next line that starts with a `$`, whether it's an `$end` or a different command? How about if you had some text in between those, like `$cmt`, `some text`, `$set ewdiw`, `efef`, `$end`. Is it accurate that `some text` is a comment here?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions. For the first one, the word following the `$` needs to be the right color (so yellow if it's a `$end` or red if it's a `$set`). For the second part, some text would be considered as comments (but i will rarely use this syntax)

Comment: @SebastienLortie Thanks for the clarifications! (You might want to edit the post to make the syntax *really* clear...) Perhaps include a small sample text that illustrates all the corner case. I'll take a look as soon as I can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
syntax clear
syntax case ignore
syntax match inCMD "\$set"
syntax match inCMD "\$cmd"
syntax match inCMD "\$end"
syntax region inCMT start=/^\$cmt/ end=/\$end\|\$\@=/

hi inCMT ctermfg=yellow
hi inCMD ctermfg=red
```

It seems to match your update indicating which color each line or word should take. Normally only the keywords (`$cmd`, `$run` and `$end`) are red, but for a comment the whole block is yellow, including the final `$end`.

The trick to match a comment with or without an `$end` was to do a zero-width match on a single `$` (that's the `\$\@=` part of the regex.) Since regular expressions return the longest match first, whenever `$end` is found it will be matched (and highlighted yellow), but if a `$` is otherwise matched, it ends the region but it doesn't become part of it, so it won't be highlighted yellow (and it turns out it's still available to be highlighted red if it's one of the other matching commands, which was important in this case.)

I noticed you had an `$end` further down one line, so I didn't anchor the commands anywhere. My first instinct was to use `^` to have them at the start of the line and also use a `$` to only allow `$end` to be by itself on a line. But I removed all that and it turns out it still works as expected. Feel free to add those back if you think they make sense.

Comment: I'll check it out soon! Thanks a lot!!